# is the way for oauth yandex in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, yandex-api

I want to oauth at google chrome extension for get token, and get some info from yandex mail at background.js.
But i cant find the way for this.

Yandex oauth work as:

1. some html link to oauth.yandex.ru/authorize
2. authorization
3. return back to the page by callback

but google chrome extension has not any url.

is it possible?

Comment: For mv3, is there other way than: buy a domain name which can be used for many extensions. Then, set the redirect url to that domain. Authenticate the user there. Then, request access to that domain from your extension to get the acquired tokens.